# Prevent ncat from terminating after running python script

Tags: python, netcat

How do I prevent ncat from terminating after running a python script?  My current netcat command is: `ncat -lvp 50000 -e main.py`. I would also like it so there can only be one connection per ip.

Comment: I think you need the -k option ("keep") to continue listening after a disconnect.

Comment: actually, 1 last question. Do you know how to make it so there can only be 1 connection per ip address? @berndbausch

Comment: It is possible to limit the number of concurrent connections with `-m`, but I don't see such an option for per-IP limitation. There is a fairly complete user guide though: https://nmap.org/ncat/guide/index.html. Perhaps you find a solution there.